# Можно ли получить все ID товаров при обене 1С с 1С bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Можно ли получить все ID товаров при обмене 1С с 1С bitrix и записать в массив.
Копал в сторону события OnCompleteCatalogImport1C но пока безуспешно.
Событие OnSuccessCatalogImport1C что-то не совсем подходит.
Подскажите куда хотя бы смотреть.
Небольшой примерчик был бы идеален.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно подойдет `catalog_product_mutator_1c`

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/1c_mutators.php

Функция вызывается для каждого товара, так что придется куда-то сохранять ID (в файл или БД).